# Android Studio Project Configuration

Tags: android

I have some questions about the "Run Configuration" and how modules work in android studio. I checked out some projects and now I want to run it, but I am confused about the relation between modules, run configurations with the project structure. Here are some screen shots from my android studio. [image: Android Stiodio]   [image: project stucture]
[image: module]

Can someone help me with the configuration?.
Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks

Comment: Did you open the project through gradle?

Comment: no, I downloaded the source code and open the project with android studio

Comment: Try to update gradle, please. I think project was builded not in correct way.

Comment: @Kyrmyzyanik  Thanks. I re-installed android studio and open the project with build gradle, now it works. You should answer the question so I can accept your answer.

Comment: thank you. I will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try to open your project through gradle or update gradle.